# Cascading Dropdown ASP MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dropdownlist

Estoy armando un ejemplo de dos dropdownlist en MVC, el primero carga los datos pero el segundo no muestra los datos según el indice.

El primer control me carga la información de los paises, pero al cambiar de **item** del primero,  el control no se actualizan ni cargan la información, según el cambio de indice del primero.  Me falta declarar algo? o llamar alguna otra libreria? o como debería trabajar? Hace varios días que vengo investigando sobre el manejo de este control, pero no logro sincronizar los controles.

```
public ActionResult LoadCountrys()
{
            List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text=  "--Select--", Value= "0"});
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "India", Value = "1" });
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "USA", Value = "2" });
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Australia", Value = "3" });
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Paskistan", Value = "4" });
            ViewData["country"] = li;
            return View();
}
 public JsonResult GetStates(string id)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> states = new List<SelectListItem>();
            switch (id)
            {
                case "1":
                    states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select--", Value = "0" });
                    states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Jammu & Kashmir", Value = "1" });
                    states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Delhi", Value = "2" });
                    states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Uttar Pradesh", Value = "3" });
                    states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Maharashtra", Value = "4" });
                    break;
                case "2":
                    states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select--", Value = "0" });
                    states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "California", Value = "1" });
                    states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Florida", Value = "2" });
                    states.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Texas", Value = "3" });
                    break;
            }
            return Json(new SelectList(states, "Value", "Text"));
        }
```

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        debugger
        $("Country").change(function () {
            $("#State").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetStates")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: $("#Country").val() },


                success: function (states) {
                    $.each(states, function (i, state) {
                        $("#State").append('<option value="' + state.Value + '">' + state.Text + '</option>');

                    });
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve states' + ex);

                }
            });
            return false;
        })
    });

</script>

<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Select Country")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @if (ViewData.ContainsKey("country"))
        {
            @Html.DropDownList("Country", ViewData["country"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { style = "width:250px;", @class = "dropdown1" })
        }
    </div>

    <br />
    <div style="color:blueviolet">
        @Html.Label("Select State", new { style= "width:250px" })
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.DropDownList("State", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value","Text"),"Please Select a State", new { style="width:250px;", @class="dropdown1" })

    </div>
```

Por otro lado, también veo en el chrome con la consola (o el inspeccionar) que tambien al cambiar el indice del control no ingresa al evento del script.

Comment: Hola, edita tu pregunta por favor, e indica en texto (código) todo lo que has puesto en imágenes, son las normas de la casa.

Comment: Saludos, bienvenido/a por favor dale una lectura a este enlace: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822